# How to implicitly insert SERIAL ID via view over more than one table

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, connected in E/R by a is-relation. One representing the "mother table"

```
CREATE TABLE PERSONS(
      id                SERIAL NOT NULL,
      name              character varying NOT NULL,
      address           character varying NOT NULL,
      day_of_creation   timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

the other representing the "child table"

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES (
      id               integer NOT NULL,
      store            character varying NOT NULL,
      paychecksize     integer NOT NULL,
      FOREIGN KEY (id)
              REFERENCES PERSONS(id),
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Now those two tables are joined in a view

```
CREATE VIEW EMPLOYEES_VIEW AS
    SELECT 
       P.id,name,address,store,paychecksize,day_of_creation
    FROM 
       PERSONS AS P
    JOIN
       EMPLOYEES AS E ON P.id = E.id
```

I want to write either a rule or a trigger to enable a db user to make an insert on that view, sparing him the nasty details of the splitted columns into different tables.

But I also want to make it convenient, as the id is a SERIAL and the `day_of_creation` has a default value there is no actual need that a user has to provide those, therefore a statement like

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES_VIEW (name, address, store, paychecksize)
VALUES ("bob", "top secret", "drugstore", 42)
```

should be enough to result in

**PERSONS**

```
id|name|address   |day_of_creation
-------------------------------
1 |bob |top secret| 2013-08-13 15:32:42
```

**EMPLOYEES**

```
id|   store |paychecksize
---------------------
1 |drugstore|42
```

A basic rule would be easy as

```
CREATE RULE EMPLOYEE_VIEW_INSERT AS ON INSERT TO EMPLOYEE_VIEW
DO INSTED (
    INSERT INTO PERSONS
    VALUES (NEW.id,NEW.name,NEW.address,NEW.day_of_creation),
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES
    VALUES (NEW.id,NEW.store,NEW.paychecksize)
)
```

should be sufficient. But this will not be convenient as a user will have to provide the id and timestamp, even though it actually is not necessary.

**How can I rewrite/extend that code base to match my criteria of convenience?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
CREATE RULE EMPLOYEE_VIEW_INSERT AS ON INSERT TO EMPLOYEES_VIEW
DO INSTEAD 
(
    INSERT INTO PERSONS (id, name, address, day_of_creation)
    VALUES (default,NEW.name,NEW.address,default);
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (id, store, paychecksize)
    VALUES (currval('persons_id_seq'),NEW.store,NEW.paychecksize)
);
```

That way the default values for `persons.id` and `persons.day_of_creation` will be the default values. Another option would have been to simply remove those columns from the insert:

```
INSERT INTO PERSONS (name, address)
VALUES (NEW.name,NEW.address);
```

Once the rule is defined, the following insert should work:

```
insert into employees_view (name, address, store, paychecksize)
values ('Arthur Dent', 'Some Street', 'Some Store', 42);
```

Btw: with a current Postgres version an `instead of` trigger is the preferred way to make a view updateable.

Comment: might sound a bit paranoid, but due to interleaving and the possibility of different users accessing those tables. Is it guaranteed, that the currval('person_id_seq') will be the correct value and not in a freakish way a higher one?

Comment: @Sim: yes, that is guaranteed. That's what sequences are for.

Comment: well, to guarantee that, a RULE has to be of atomic execution (therefore no interleaving possible), I do not quite understand how the implementation of sequence might be of any influence there?

Comment: how come a trigger is the preferred way, rules seem to be made to do such stuff? Any non-subjective reasons to prefer trigger over rules?

Comment: The "guarantee" has nothing to do with a rule (or it's atomicity - which it automatically has because it's run in a transaction). It's the way sequences work. Regarding rules vs. triggers. [From the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-triggers.html): "*the trigger approach is conceptually far simpler than the rule approach, and is easier for novices to get right*"

Comment: @Sim The value returned by `currval` is local to the session. It wont be affected in any way by other user sessions.